# Hash / Array - Formatting Issue with ConvertTo-Json

Tags: powershell

I'm taking a list of users, and then using the following code to loop through them and build a chunk needed for a json request in a specific format.

```
$teamMembers = @();
foreach ($item in $userIds) {
    $team = @{
        id = $item
        type = 'User'
        roleTypes = @(
            'TeamContributor'
        )
    }
    $teamMembers += $team
}
```

After this hash list is created, I then need to append it to a string as follows to create a JSON string.

```
$body=@{name=$name;teamMembers=$teamMembers} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

The issue i'm having is that when I run the `ConvertTo-Json`, it's ignoring my `roleTypes` array and treating it as a string.

If I run the `ConvertTo-Json` command on just the `$teamMembers` variable it looks file, but when I combine it to build the body variable that's where it goes wrong.

Here is the example of the desired format of this output:

```
{
    "name": "Name Here",
    "teamMembers": [
        {
            "roleTypes": [ "TeamContributor" ],
            "id": "ID Here",
            "type": "User"
        },
        {
            "roleTypes": [ "TeamContributor" ],
            "id": "ID Here",
            "type": "User"
        },
    ]
}
```

Here is what i'm getting instead:

```
{
    "name": "Name Here",
    "teamMembers": [
        {
            "roleTypes": "TeamContributor " ,
            "id": "ID Here",
            "type": "User"
        },
        {
            "roleTypes": "TeamContributor " ,
            "id": "ID Here",
            "type": "User"
        },
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?  Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Up the maximum serialization depth: `... |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes - that did the trick!  Thanks!